Compute $r$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x^r} \neq 0$?
I am trying to compute $r$ such that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x^r} \neq 0$$
I tried a few things, mostly multiplying it by some conjugate and using identities like $e^{\log(x)}=x$ but couldn't find out. In the book, the answer seems to be $r=\frac{1}{2}$ but I can't manipulate it in order to get this value. Can you help me?
In the book I'm reading (Efimov's Higher Mathematics), this is called "computing the order of $3^{\sqrt{x}}-1$ relative to $x$".

Looking at this expression, my immediate thought is: this is a difference quotient or at least it's trying to be one. To reveal this more clearly, I might consider the substitution $u = \sqrt x$, so $x = u^2$ and
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3^{\sqrt{x}} - 1}{x^r} 
= \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{3^u - 1}{u^{2r}}. 
$$
Now, the numerator looks like $f(u) - f(0)$ for the exponential function $f(t) = 3^t$. This means that with $u - 0 = u$ in the denominator,
$$
\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{3^u - 1}{u - 0} = f'(0), 
$$
which I know converges, since $f$ is differentiable at $t = 0$. In fact, I know the value of the derivative (which is the limit) by using familiar derivative formulas:
$$
f'(0) = \ln 3 \neq 0.
$$
In conclusion, with $r = \tfrac12$, the limit converges.

Now, we have to show that for other values of $r$, the limit either converges to zero or diverges to infinity. But this follows from limit rules by writing $r = \tfrac12 + \bigl(r - \tfrac12\bigr)$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3^{\sqrt{x}} - 1}{x^r} 
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3^{\sqrt{x}} - 1}{x^{1/2}} 
\cdot \frac{1}{x^{r - 1/2}} 
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln 3}{x^{r - 1/2}}.
$$
If $r < \tfrac12$ so that $r - \tfrac12 < 0$, then this converges to $0$. And if $r > \tfrac12$ so that $r - \tfrac12 > 0$, then this divergest to $\infty$. This rules out all other values of $r$.

Do you happen to know how to compute it without using analogies with the derivative? The book still didn't mention derivatives up to this point and I'm trying to remain faithful to the spirit of the book.

With l'Hopital's rule.
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x^r} \ne 0$
$ \frac{3^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x^r} \to \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot \ln 3 \cdot 3^{\sqrt{x}}}{rx^{r-1}}=\frac{\ln 3 \cdot 3^{\sqrt{x}}}{2rx^{r-1/2}}\implies r=1/2$

Without derivatives.
Let $u=\sqrt{x}$
Find $\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{3^u-1}{u^{2r}}$
$\frac{3^u-1}{u^{2r}}=\frac{3^u-1}{u}\cdot \frac{1}{u^{2r-1}}$
For the left factor:
$\frac{3^u-1}{u}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{(1+\frac{u\ln 3}{n})^n-1}{u}= \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{1}{u}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{n}{k}(\frac{u \ln 3}{n})^k=\ln 3$
Since only the first term in the sum is non-zero.
The limit of the right factor is $0$ or $\infty$ unless $r=1/2$.
